# resultcallback for cast.API.pauseMedia times out

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I am working on a very basic HTML5 video sender/receiver application using the Chrome API (Cast Chrome) and I am having trouble with the cast.API.pauseMedia method in the sender application.  In the sender application I have buttons that mimic those in a video player to control playback on the receiver.  I have one button for play/pause that should change it's image and onclick handler (playMedia or pauseMedia) depending on whether the video is currently playing or is paused.  To make sure the buttons are set to the correct state, I check the result of playMedia/pauseMedia, but the problem I am having is that the pauseMedia resultCallback (MediaResult) is always false with an error string "Request timeout".  Note: the video does play/pause correctly at the receiver, but with pause always returning false, I am unable to use the result to update the UI.

Here is the relevant code:

```
function playMedia() {
    castApi.playMedia(currentActivityId, new cast.MediaPlayRequest(), function(result) {
            console.log("onPlay [activityId: " +result.activityId + "] [result: " + result.success + "] [ErrorString: " + result.errorString + "] [Status: " + JSON.stringify(result.status) + "]");
            if (result.success) {
                document.getElementById("play-pause").onclick = pauseMedia;
                document.getElementById("play-pause").innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause fa-fw"></i>';                
            }
        });
}

function pauseMedia() {
    castApi.pauseMedia(currentActivityId, function(result) {
        console.log("onPause [activityId: " +result.activityId + "] [result: " + result.success + "] [ErrorString: " + result.errorString + "] [Status: " + JSON.stringify(result.status) + "]");
            if (result.success) {
                document.getElementById("play-pause").onclick = playMedia;
                document.getElementById("play-pause").innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play fa-fw"></i>';       
            }  
        });    
}
```

and here is the console.log output:

```
onPause [activityId: ra06rhvtqgdb] [result: false] [ErrorString: Request timeout] [Status: null]

onPlay [activityId: ra06rhvtqgdb] [result: true] [ErrorString: null] [Status: {"eventSequenceId":85,"activityId":"ra06rhvtqgdb","state":2,"contentId":"http://192.168.1.73/videos/tears_of_steel_1080p.mov","title":null,"imageUrl":null,"timeProgress":false,"position":3,"duration":734.167,"volume":1,"muted":false,"contentInfo":null,"mediaTracks":[],"error":null,"hasPause":null}]
```

I noticed that "status" (MediaPlayerStatus) includes a "hasPause" field which is null.  I suspect that this might have something to do with the problem (is that the case?), but I am not sure what controls the value of that field.  The documentation for "hasPause" states: "Whether player supports pauseMedia and playMedia commands. Most receiver applications should support this, however, some applications may not support these functions.".  Both playMedia and pauseMedia do seem to be working (the video does play and pause at the receiver), but "hasPause" is always null.  Am I supposed to set this value myself in the receiver application, and if so, how to do it?

EDIT: Adding more info as there is not much space in the comments.
I used the helloChromecast example here: https://github.com/googlecast/cast-chrome-sender-helloworld as a starting point.  I modified the receiver.html to add a missing `</video>` tag and added an onEnded function (so I get notified when the video has finished playing, etc). I modified the sender such that I can enter a video URL manually and added my own custom player controls (play/pause, seek-bar, video position indicator, mute button, and volume-bar, etc).  I can get the functionality to work using a number of methods, but the goal here is just learning the API, so I am trying to understand why it is not working with the method used here.  e.g. If I just ignored the result of pauseMedia, everything works fine, and I could also call getMediaStatus to verify the playerstate to keep the buttons sync'd, etc, but that does not help me to understand why pauseMedia always returns false, or why hasPause is always null, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you call castApi.getMediaStatus(activityId, callback) when it is playing and when it is paused, what do you get for status in your callback? You should see either 0 (for idle), 1 (for stopped) or 2 (for playing). Note that the argument passed to the callback (say, "result") has a field status whose "state" should give you that value: result.status.state
 Also, you should see status changes on the sender automatically since the standard receiver broadcasts the status change of the player. Have you written your own receiver? Are you seeing the status change messages on the sender side at all?

Comment: Yes, I can see the correct player state information when I call getMediaStatus.  As for seeing the changes automatically, I am not sure what you are referring to.  I do not know of any Cast Chrome examples that show this information automatically (e.g. like a onStatusChanged event listener?).  I am using a modified version of the helloChromecast example here: https://github.com/googlecast/cast-chrome-sender-helloworld

Comment: (Ran out of space) The sender has buttons to get that info, but it is no automatic (i.e. calls getMediaStatus when clicked).  I modified the sender so that I can enter a video url manually and added my own custom player controls.  I am basically just playing around with it (for the sake of learning the API), and am trying to make an interface more like Netflix or YouTube uses. The receiver is only slightly modified (added a missing </video> tag, and added a onEnded function). I could make it work using other methods but why isn't pauseMedia's result ever successful and how to use hasPause?

Comment: I don't believe you can get much from "hasPause"; it is not currently set by the receiver (hence "null); if I were to guess, I would say that was "intended" to be used to indicate whether the stream could be paused or not (e.g. live tv may not be paused) but that is a pure speculation on my side. Anyhow, the best approach that I would suggest is to run a timer (with repeat interval of a second or so) to fetch the status and interpret that accordingly. A better/cleaner solution might be to hook into the "video" element's events on the receiver and send a message back to the connected sender(s).

Comment: Yeah, I think you are probably right and maybe some of the cast.receiver.RemoteMedia stuff is not completely implemented yet. I just thought that maybe there was something I was missing. Using the HTML5 video elements events directly sounds like it is probably a better way to go. For some reason I was thinking I could not do that   on the receiver and could only use the RAMP stuff for remote video.  Thanks for the replies.